# How can I get this pregnant woman to work?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have this really intelligent pregnant women stuck in the living quaters...
I can't make her work 
Anyone have any Solutions to this problem?

Comment: Could you provide more information? She is certainly support to be able to work, but without any more information, it is hard to tell you whats going wrong. What happens when you try to drag her into another room?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to happen from time to time. What helped me is restarting the app, afterwards i could send her to work normally.